# Subversion error, but I don't know what it means

Tags: svn

I'm trying to do an Update on my solution but I'm getting the following subversion error:

> SharpSvn.SvnFileSystemException:
>   Working copy path 'Path_to_image/logo
>   LoRes.jpg' does not exist in
>   repository

but I can see that the image *is* in the repository.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Update(ICollection`1 paths, SvnUpdateArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Update(String path, SvnUpdateArgs args, SvnUpdateResult& result)
   at Ankh.Commands.SolutionUpdateCommand.UpdateRunner.Work(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

Is there something else that could be wrong?

Comment: Could it be the space in "logo LoRes.jpg" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatever it was, who knows.. but I seem to have fixed it anyway. i deleted the local copy and got the latest from the repository again and then I was able to do the update.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a case sensitivity issue - does the name of the image in the repository and on your machine perhaps differ in case?

SVN servers are usually run on Linux, where file names are case sensitive, and can get very confused when dealing with Windows clients where this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's not it though.. the case in svn is the same as what I have locally